# jQuery replace element and access that replaced element

Tags: jquery

I'm in progress to learn jQuery. I want to add a feature so when user clicks on a `td` with a specified class name, I want to change it into an `select` option. And with that selected value i want to update my db.

Until here its okay. I can change the `td` to an `input` however, I can't add an event on change event to that replaced element.

Here is what I have:

```
(function($) {

    var _defaults = {
        some : "defaults",
    };

    $.fn.changetoi = function(options) {

        var _opts = $.extend({}, _defaults, options);

        $(this).on('click', function() {
            var replaced = $('<select name="status" class="changer"><option>Test</option></select>');
            $(this).replaceWith(replaced);
        });

        $('.changer').on('change', function() { //here I'm try to access the changed element
            var value = $(".changer option:selected").text();
            //post the selected value
            $.post("test.php", {
                "value" : value
            }, function(data) {
                //whatever and
                $(this).replaceWith(value);
            });
        });

    };

    $('.change').changetoi();
})(jQuery);
```

and here is the fiddle for table, test and such http://jsfiddle.net/HZvH8/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the handler like so:

```
$(document).on('change', '.changer', function() {
```

This element doesn't exist at DOM ready, therefore you bind the `change()` event to an element that is there.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/HZvH8/5/

Comment: i did not know that thanks. So can we assume that all element that are changed after page loaded not exist at DOM and we need to add an event like that?

Comment: Elements that are added after DOM ready should have the handlers binded via `.on()` -- http://api.jquery.com/on/